# Template logic based out of two different text

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Need to show two different texts based out of a boolean Value.

I tried this

```
    <div name="health-plans" *ngIf="!flagon">
      Test<br />data
    </div>`

`        <div name="health-plans" *ngIf="flagon">
          Test data <br /> & value
        </div>
```

But I need to simpify this with one div based out on condition.

Comment: <div name="health-plans">
  Test data <br /> {{ flagon ? '& value' : '' }}
</div>

Answer (score 1):

#### Angular 17+

```
<div name="health-plans">
  @if (!flagon) {
    Test<br />data
  }
  @else {
    Test data <br /> & value
  }
</div>
```

#### Angular <17

```
<div name="health-plans">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!flagon; else FlagonTemplate">
    Test<br />data
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #FlagonTemplate>
    Test data <br /> & value
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use ng-container, instead I need to use only div, is there any approach for that ?

Comment: @moh's comment will suffice for simple use cases where differing HTML elements are not required, i.e. use interpolation (`{{}}`) and add logic to show different content based on your variable. For more complex use cases where you want to render completely different HTML in the `true` and `false` cases, an `ng-template` will be required as in this example

Comment: But the first div value (Test<br />data) wont satisfy right based on @moh's comment

Comment: Ahh yes you are correct, as the position of the `<br />` is not standard in both pieces of text; I hadn't actually noticed that! I suppose you could implement two sets of `{{}}` before and after the `<br />` but personally I think it's cleaner to just introduce the `ng-container`